# Converting columns to rows in oracle 11gR1

Tags: sql, oracle11g, unpivot

I saw there many example on this site but still i havent got any solution.So iam posting the question.

Please suggest me how can i resolve this issue. Iam working on oracle **11gR1 version**.

```
year         price     Quantity
1991           10        50
2008           20        96
```

I want output as

```
1991  10
1991  20
2008  50
2008  96
```

I tried with pivot function but not achieved and getting exception as SQL command not terminated properly.
below is my query. Iam not good in sql .

```
select * from   (select year, price ,quanty from my_table )
       pivot( min(year)  year  in (price, quanty) );
```

**Edit for above question:**

```
select year, value
from my_table
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (price, quantity)
) u
```

For the above query, if i have one more column by name Name of Product which is varchar, iam getting and i pass the column in above query as below .

```
select year, value
    from my_table
    unpivot
    (
      value
      for col in (price, quantity,productname)
    ) u
```

getting error as

**ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression**

Please @BlueFeet suggest on this.

Comment: The ORA-01790 error is self-explanatory error, don't you think so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you need to [`UNPIVOT`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) instead of pivot.  The unpivot is the process of converting multiple rows into multiple columns.

Since you are using Oracle 11g, you can use the unpivot function:

```
select year, value
from my_table
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (price, quantity)
) u
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6b10f/1).

You could also write this using `UNION ALL`:

```
select year, price as value
from my_table
union all
select year, quantity as value
from my_table
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6b10f/2)

Based on the fact that you also want to include a `varchar` column in the final result, you'll need to convert the columns to all be the same datatype - you can do this in a subquery:

```
select year, value
from
(
  select year, 
    to_char(price) as price,
    to_char(quantity) as quantity,
    productname
  from my_table
)
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (price, quantity, productname)
) u;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66d750/3)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with t(year, price, Quantity) as(
  select 1991, 10, 50 from dual union all
  select 2008, 20, 96 from dual 
)
select year, new_col1
  from t
unpivot (
  new_col1 for new_col in (price, quantity))

YEAR    NEW_COL1
----------------
1991    10
1991    50
2008    20
2008    96
```

Read more [here](http://diefororacle.blogspot.ru/2014/08/pivot-sql-extenssion-for-oracle-database.html)