# Breaking columns into rows by column name

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following Table...

TABLE_A

```
emp_id | A_column_1 | A_column_2
 80001 | Apple      | 10
 80002 | Orange     | 3
 80003 | Banana     | 5
```

I'm able to capture the columns of this table by querying all_tab_columns

```
 SELECT column_name
 FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_A';
```

result...

```
| column_name |
| A_column_1  |  
| A_column_2  |
```

I'd like write a query that breaks out the columns in TABLE_A into rows that match their corresponding column name in the all_tab_columns query. The result would looks like...

View 1

```
emp_id | View_column_1 | View_column_2
 80001 | Apple         | A_column_1
 80001 | 10            | A_column_2
 80002 | Orange        | A_column_1
 80002 | 3             | A_column_2
 80003 | Banana        | A_column_1
 80003 | 5             | A_column_2
```

Is this possible without hard coding values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting columns to rows in oracle 11gR1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684650/converting-columns-to-rows-in-oracle-11gr1)

Comment: Almost! I would also need the column name added to the row, though. That seems to be the part that doesn't seem possible in PL/SQL.

Comment: Remove all the columns in the `select` list and you'll get exactly what you want

Comment: Which select list? If I removed all columns from a select list the sql wouldn't run?

Comment: I mean `select *` of course

Comment: I’m not sure how running the query in your solution would supply the column name as a row value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Alex Poole - How to Unpivot Dynamic Columns in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637308/how-to-unpivot-with-dynamic-columns-oracle), you may try the solution below :

Simply put,

- First `LISTAGG` is to get the dynamic columns
- Second `LISTAGG` is to convert "a_column_1" and "a_column_2" into the same data type
- `sql_stmt` creates a view, so you can `SELECT * FROM V_TABLE_A` to see the results.

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lMYwn02L)

```
DECLARE
  sql_stmt CLOB;
  subquery CLOB;
  pivot_clause CLOB;

BEGIN
  SELECT 
    LISTAGG(column_name || ' AS ''' || column_name || '''', ',') 
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name),
    LISTAGG(CASE WHEN data_type = 'NUMBER' THEN 'TO_CHAR(' || column_name || ')' ELSE column_name END || ' AS ' || column_name, ',')
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name)
  INTO pivot_clause, subquery
  FROM all_tab_columns
  WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_A'
  AND column_name NOT IN ('EMP_ID');

  sql_stmt := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TABLE_A AS
    SELECT emp_id, view_column_1, view_column_2
    FROM (SELECT emp_id, ' || subquery || ' FROM TABLE_A)
    UNPIVOT (view_column_1 FOR view_column_2 IN (' || pivot_clause || '))';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(sql_stmt);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer. Do you know if it's possible to do this without generating a view and instead just fetch the results?

Comment: Never mind, dumb question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Select emp_id, A_column_1 as View_column_1, 'A_column_1' as View_column_2
From TABLE_A
Union all
Select emp_id, A_column_2 as View_column_1, 'A_column_2' as View_column_2
From TABLE_A
.

You can use order by if necessary:)

Comment: Thank you for your solution, Khalido. Sadly, I'm not able to hardcode the column names. I'm in need of a general solution that will work even when other columns are added.